# jquery-select for additional rows

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to use jquery-select2 in my select dropdown form. The form is in a table row and I can add new rows with the Add Button. When I click the Add Button it will make more rows for me and I have data that is generated from the database.

The problem is that the jquery-select2 only works for the select dropdown in the first row, but it does not function for the new rows I create. I have tried the $('#idone').select2(); , but it didn’t work. Below is my select form and code.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
   <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" id="dataTable" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
     
<td colspan="4" align="left"><button id="alertred" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-flat pull-left delete_row" >Delete Row</button></td>
<td colspan="3" align="right"><button id="button2" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-flat pull-right add_row"> Add Row</button></td>
  </tr>
                          <tr>  
         <td ></td>
         <td>Dropdown One</td>
         <td>Dropdown Two</td>
        <td>details</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        
      </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr valign="baseline" id="main_tr" class="main_tr" >
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="deleterow" class="deleterow" ></td>     
        <td><select name="idone[]" class="onesub form-control" id="idone" required>
          <option value="0">Select Account</option>
          <option value="1">Laravel</option>
                                <option value="2">Jquery</option>
                                <option value="3">PHP</option>
                                <option value="4">React</option>
                                <option value="5">Jquery ui</option>
                                <option value="6">Android</option>
</select> 
<select name="subone[]" class="suboneid" type="hidden"><option></option></select>
</td>

 <td><select name="idtwo[]" class="twosub form-control" id="idtwo" required>
          <option value="0">Select Account</option>
          <option value="1">Laravel</option>
                                <option value="2">Jquery</option>
                                <option value="3">PHP</option>
                                <option value="4">React</option>
                                <option value="5">Jquery ui</option>
                                <option value="6">Android</option>
        </select>   
       </td>

        <td><input type="text" name="details[]" id="details" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="date" name="dateofentry[]" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>   
      <tr >      
        <td colspan="7" align="center"><input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit"></td>       
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the script to add more rows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".add_row").click(function(){
       var main_tr = $('#main_tr').clone();
       var ml = $(".main_tr").length;
       main_tr.find("label").remove();
       main_tr.find("input").val("");
       main_tr.find("select").val("");
       main_tr.find("#idone").attr("id","idone"+ml );
       main_tr.find("#idtwo").attr("id","idtwo"+ml );
       main_tr.find("#details").attr("id","details"+ml );
       main_tr.find("#date").attr("id","date"+ml );
       $(main_tr).insertAfter('.main_tr:last');
      });
      $(".delete_row").click(function(){
        $(".deleterow:checked").each(function () {
          $(this).parents('.main_tr').remove();
        });

      });
    });
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
    });
  });
  
  $(function() {
    $('#idone').select2();
     $('#idtwo').select2();
});
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("body").on("change",".onesub",function(){
  var headid=$(this).val();
  var that = $(this);
  var post_id = 'headid='+ headid;
  $.ajax
  ({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajaxpostone.php",
      data: post_id,
      cache: false,
      success: function(suboneid)
      {
        $(that).parents("tr").find(".suboneid").html(suboneid);
      } 
  });

  });  
});
    </script>
```

How do I make this jquery-select2 work for the select dropdown in first row and every other new row I add to my form table.

Comment: _"I have tried the $('#idone').select2(); , but it didn’t work."_ - that is probably because what you are cloning and inserting there, already contains other stuff besides the ID attribute, that refers to a specific select2 instance. If you log the HTML of your `main_tr` element before appending it to the document, you'll see `<select ... id="idone1" ... data-select2-id="idone"` in there. And you are cloning the additional HTML that select2 already inserted as well, lots of `idone` reference in there too.

Comment: Ok,I see what you mean, but how do I solve this I am really short of ideas.

Comment: Might make sense to go with a [`template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element to get you something "clean", that can then be cloned as many times as possible.